# bootstrap collapse in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

i'm trying to make sure that each time when new collapse is create it will open only the one that were chosen. right now it just open all when click and close all at the same time

```
<div ng-repeat = "i in ticket_array">
<div ng-repeat="j in getNumber(i) track by $index">
div class="panel-group" ng-click="expand()">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" >Collapsible panel</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$scope.expand = function(){
       $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
    };  
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    console.log(num);
    return new Array(parseInt(num.quantity));   
    };
```

it create an 3 new collapse but i don know how to make sure it only open the were chosen.

i have try using index it but did not work since my array consist of two object that has the same index

this is my array
[{"type":"men junior", "quantity":"3"},{"type":"men senior", "quantity":"3"}]

Comment: can you provide a JS fiddle by any chance?

Comment: You can add a unique ID to each div that collapses, ie `collapse-$index`. Then call `expand($index)` where the body would be `$('#collapse-' + $index).collapse('toggle');`

Comment: @NTL i try using index but my array has something like this 
[{"type":"men junior", "quantity":"3"}], [{"type":"men senior", "quantity":"3"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pure Js to change HTML behaviour into an angular Project is never a good idea.

Have a look at this project for an angular implementation of your collapse : http://embed.plnkr.co/tcTZlA/

The idea is to have a variable that stores a boolean to activate or not your accordeon menu.

In your case ; I'd change your code with :

```
<div ng-repeat = "i in ticket_array">
<div ng-repeat="j in getNumber(i) track by $index">
<div class="panel-group" ng-click="j.active = !j.active" ng-class="{'expandcollapse-heading-collapsed': j.active, 'expandcollapse-heading-expanded': !j.active}"> // CODE EDITED HERE WITH A NEW VARIABLE
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" >Collapsible panel</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And of course adding some CSS for the transition :

```
.expandcollapse-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top:1px solid blue;
}

.expandcollapse-heading-collapsed {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000000;
  color: black; 
  background-color: white;

}

.expandcollapse-item:first-of-type {
  border-top:0px;
}


.expandcollapse-heading-collapsed h4{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in this you can make use of $event to add target and specify the inner collapse class. $event will trace the event where it is called like this in javascript. and you can take this event to handle manipulation in your function.

```
 <div ng-repeat = "i in ticket_array">
    <div ng-repeat="j in getNumber(i) track by $index">
    <div class="panel-group" ng-click="expand($event)">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" >Collapsible panel</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    $scope.expand = function($event){
           $($event.target).find('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
        };
```

updated solution:

```
$scope.expand = function($event){
   if($($event.target).find('.collapse').hasClass('in')){
        $($event.target).find('.collapse').removeClass('in')
   }else{
        $($event.target).find('.collapse').addClass('in')
   }
};
```

Comment: it didn't work the was no error anc collapse did not open at all